# Kaleido fails to start inside docker

Tags: docker, plotly, plotly-dash, kaleido

I have a working plotly dash project that generates png files when I run it in my local environment.  I now set up a docker container and generating png does suddenly not work anymore.

Error:

```
"File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py", line 3821, in write_image
return pio.write_image(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_kaleido.py", line 268, in write_image
img_data = to_image(
File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_kaleido.py", line 145, in to_image
img_bytes = scope.transform(
File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\kaleido\scopes\plotly.py", line 153, in transform
response = self._perform_transform(
File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\kaleido\scopes\base.py", line 293, in _perform_transform
self._ensure_kaleido()
File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\kaleido\scopes\base.py", line 198, in _ensure_kaleido
raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Failed to start Kaleido subprocess"
```

Used Docker Enviroment:

- windows servercore mcr from microsoft, "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019"
- python 3.8.6
- kaleido 0.2.1
- plotly 5.3.1
- dash 2.0.0

Is there a way to solve this ?